# magento 2.1 getParentCategories for category id

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

i try to get getParentCategories for category id

```
 // 4 is product id 
$product = $this->_productFactory->load(4);
$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
$category = $this->categoryFactory->create();
         $collection = $category->getResourceCollection();
         $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $cats)
                    ->addIsActiveFilter()
                    ->load();
//\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category = $this->category 
foreach ($collection as $cat) {
              $data = $this->category->getParentCategories($cat->getId());
              echo "<pre/>"; print_r($data); exit;
              //$cat->getId();
          } exit;
```

This code is working in 2.0.7 but not working in 2.1

Answer (score 1):

In the Magento 2.1 version, look at `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Category.php`. 
As we can see, the `getParentCategories($category)` method needs an argument which is an instance of category model.

So, in your case, it should be: `$this->category->getParentCategories($cat)`.

Comment: i try to pass category instance but it's not working.

Comment: Your `$this->category` gets the category collection as well? Try to `var_dump` some values.

Comment: @Pratik Still not working?

Answer (score 0):

It's Working but i think code is not proper way because i loop object see code

```
$product = $this->_productFactory->load($pid);
        $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
        if (empty($cats))
            return '';

         $category = $this->categoryFactory->create();
         $collection = $category->getResourceCollection();
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $cats)
                ->addIsActiveFilter()
                ->load();

          $result = '';

        foreach ($collection as $cat) {
            $names = array();

            foreach ($this->category->getParentCategories($cat) as $parent) {
                $names[] = $parent->getName();
            }

            foreach ($names as $key => $label) {
               echo $label;
            }
        }
```

Comment: So, using `$this->category->getParentCategories($cat)`  can solve your issue?

Comment: Yes but i think this is not good solution.

Comment: Yes, you can share me a good solution? I only show you a change in M2.1 version.  That causes your issue.